# Formatting Text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I had two textview in a linearlayout. In one textview, text contains 21 characters and in another textview, text contains only 12 characters. The first textview is shown in two lines and the second textview is shown in single line. I want both textview text should be same either in single or double line.

I used the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtextview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtextview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by  `should be same` mean height?

Comment: Do you want to keep the same text size?

Comment: You don't need: `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:minLines="2"` in both `<TextView>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

If you want both of them to be single line use `android:singleLine="true"` :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Some of the characters are not displayed in first textview

Answer (score 0):

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Also both your textviews have the exact same id. You might want to change that.

Comment: If I set android:singleLine="true", some of the characters are not showing in first textview

Comment: remove the singleLine and try android:lines="2"

Answer (score 0):

you can set attributes:

```
android:lines="2"
android:maxLines="2"
```

for both TextViews

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code for fix height of text views

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtextview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="sdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsd"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtextview2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="2"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="sdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsd"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically retrieve the width of your screen and the maximum width of the 2 texts. If the text width is bigger than the screen width then set the `TextView` number of lines to 2 in your case. Else, to 1.

Use `Paint` to calculate the width of the text.

```
    int screenWidth = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    TextView t1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tvtextview1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tvtextview2);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    String longText = "123456789012345678901";

    paint.setTextSize(30);

    float textWidth = paint.measureText(longText);

    if((int)textWidth > screenWidth)
    {
        t1.setLines(2);
        t2.setLines(2);
    } else
        {
            t1.setLines(2);
            t2.setLines(2);
        }
```